# I can't separate the array by commas

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem I cannot separate the array by commas if I put the implode it only shows the first number and not the second in database i need insert in database 500,756

```
global $wpdb;  $arg=array(500,756);

$var = implode(",", $arg);   --> return in db 500 ->I can not separate by commas, num 500 is only show in db 
$var = implode($arg);        --> if i put this instead of the other return in db shows 500756

     $wpdb->insert('number',array( 
          'num' => $var,   
        ));
```

```
CREATE TABLE `number` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `num` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `number`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `number`
  MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=39;
```

Comment: What type is the `num` column? If it's an integer column of any kind then you can't insert comma separated values.

Comment: are you trying to insert 1 row with the value "500,756" or are you trying to insert two rows with one : 500 and the other 765?

Comment: Data type is varchar but only saves 500

Answer (score 0):

`implode(",", [500,756])` will definitely return `"500,756"`, therefore you have some other problem.

If the field type of the 'num' field is a numeric type such as MySQL's INT, then MySQL or PHP might try and convert this string to a number and so `"500,756"` could become `500`.

Check the data type of the 'num' field in the 'number' table. To store the string you want to store it needs to be a string type such as VARCHAR. Or if you're trying to store a number with stuff after the decimal point make sure it's e.g. a FLOAT / DECIMAL, etc. and add the value using a decimal point, e.g. `500.756`.

If you need further help, show the CREATE TABLE output for your table

Comment: I have put the sql code in the publication

Comment: looks fine, perhaps you're not looking at the right row when looking for the result, or left your second like in which would overwrite the $var variable